# Verifying execution of code in trustless environment

Tags: computation-models, distributed-systems, logical-validity

Let us assume I have a Program P running on remote computer generating output O. Without trusting the remote environment and not having to verify the output O, is there is a way to validate that Program P has indeed been executed and resulted in output O ?

Let me know if the question is too vague. I will clarify.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Is P known to the verifier, and he wants to be convinced that the "remote environment" is in the possession of $O$, the output of $P$?

Comment: Yes. P is know to the verifier. Verifier (V) wants to be sure that execution of P resulted in O. Trustless node T might cheat by submitting random O. V wants to ensure that what ever O might be, it is indeed generated by execution of P.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/38837/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/80169/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem of securely outsourcing computation.  There's lots of work on this problem in the cryptographic literature; if you do a search at [Crypto.SE] and [Security.SE], you should find some references.  Many of the schemes are probabilistic: if you the remote computer cheats, you have some chance of detecting that fact.  I know of two general approaches: one based on cryptographic commitments, and another based on SNARKs. You should be able to turn up papers on  how SNARKs work.